# Как в папке удалить каждое изображение которое весит определённое количество байт, но по отдельности

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, list, ос

Я хочу, чтобы он пробегался по каждому изображению, и если оно равно 503 байтам, то он его удалял и продолжал дальше искать похожие изображения

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
import os

from rich.console import Console
from rich.theme import Theme

i = 1 #Я не начинаю с 0, потому что не хочу первое изображение удалять - **'TestPhotoDontDelete.jpg'**
image_path = glob.glob('image/*.jpg')
print('1: ', image_path) #Оно будет = ['image\\TestPhotoDontDelete.jpg', **'image\\7dwipf.jpg'**, 'image\\fwm1q3.jpg']

image_path = [x.split('\\')[1] for x in image_path] 
print('2: ', image_path) #А теперь = ['TestPhotoDontDelete.jpg', '**7dwipf.jpg'**, 'fwm1q3.jpg']

for x in image_path:
    image_size = os.path.getsize(image_path[i]) #Отсюда беру размер фото
    i += 1 #Прохожусь по каждому элементу в списке (то есть фото в папке)
    print("image_size2: ", image_size) #Вывожу размер первого элемента в байтах
    if image_size[i] == 503: #Если размер байтов в этом элементе равен 503:
        console.print("[red]ЕСТЬ ОШИБКА[/]") #Просто вывожу сообщение
        os.remove(image_path[i]) #Здесь я пытаюсь удалить эту фотку, но у меня ошибка в консоли
    else:
        console.print("[green]НЕТ ОШИБКИ[/]")
```

ошибка:

```
1:  ['image\\!TestPhotoDontDelete.jpg', '**image\\7dwipf.jpg'**, 'image\\fwm1q3.jpg']
2:  ['!TestPhotoDontDelete.jpg', **'7dwipf.jpg'**, 'fwm1q3.jpg']
File "Main", line 77, in photodel #Это функция
    image_size = os.path.getsize(image_path[i])
  File "C:\Users\alexx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size #Это не из запускаемого кода, а чёт другое
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: **'7dwipf.jpg'** #Хотя он в списке есть, и даже в самой папке имеется...
```

Вроде я всё объяснил, помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если не хотите читать первое изображение, то просто возьмите срез списка без него.

```
import glob
import os


SIZE_DELETE = 503

image_path = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for file in image_path[1:]:
    if os.path.getsize(file) == SIZE_DELETE:
        os.remove(file)
```

У Вас возникала ошибка потому что при попытки удалить передаете только имя файла, а не полный путь `os.remove(image_path[i])`